# input Search = includes keep returning Null

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an input search to search for certain values in an array of objects fetched from a certain API... but each time I use the javascript code it returns `null`

```js
const search_input = document.querySelector('.input_search')
function searchCharacter() {
    fetch(api)
    .then(function(e){
        return e.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        let characters = [];
        characters.push(...data) 
        search_input.addEventListener('keyup' , (e) => {
        const input_string = e.target.value
        const filterSearch =  characters.filter( e => {
               return  e.name.includes(input_string)

        })
        console.log(filterSearch)
    })    
})}
searchCharacter();
```

if i switched e.name with e.short_name or e.shortnames[0] i works just fine , but i need for the function too look up the name since they are more readable this img of the structure of the array
[image]

Edit : Problem solved

```js
const search_input = document.querySelector('.input_search')
function searchCharacter() {
    fetch(api)
    .then(function(e){
        return e.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        // Creat Array and filter out the null objects.
        let characters = [];
        let characters_filter = [];
        characters.push(...data) 
        characters.filter( e => {
            if (e.name !== null) {
                characters_filter.push(e)
            } return
            })
            
            // creat input search event
            search_input.addEventListener('input' , (e) => {
                const input_string = e.target.value;
                const filter_array = characters_filter.filter( e => {
                    return e.name.toLowerCase().includes(input_string)
                })
                console.log(filter_array) 
            })
        }) 
    }
    
searchCharacter();
```

P.S. thanks for everyone for pointing me out to the right direction

Comment: What's the value of `input_string`?

Comment: value ? mostly lower case like "flag" without quotation i tired uppcase same problem...

Comment: You are saying it "returns null" but `.filter` will always return an array, so it's unclear what exactly you are referring to. Could you be more specific?

Comment: in case i use `return  e.name.includes(input_string)`, `.filter` returns red error => e.name value is Null but , in case i switched to `return  e.short_name.includes(input_string)` and used upper case or lower case value to initiate the search it works just fine . what i need is for the filter method to look inside the object proprieties using the name instead of short_name or short_names since it's more readable.

Comment: That's a completely different result. That's an actual error, not a return value. It means that some objects in the array have `name: null` as value, not a string. Just like `text: null` in your screenshot above. You have to decide how you want to handle entries that don't have a "full" name. E.g. you might decide that you want to fall back to using `short_name` in these cases.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks problem solved it's really as you said !!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming from your question that your input_string is "hash" in your example?

This will currently not work with e.name because it's all uppercase and your search term is lower case.

```
const e = {
    name: "HASH",
};
const input_string = "hash";

console.log(e.name.toLowerCase().includes(input_string)); // returns true
```

Depending on how your input_string is defined, you should probably turn that to lowercase as well.

Comment: i tired to use lowercase didn't work it's still returns null , tried to use lower case in short_name case turn out it's does return an empty array in case of uppercase and works fine in case of lower case i dunno why it's just refuses to work for e.name the problem is that it's returns nothing be it upper or lower

Comment: Have you tried just logging e.name on it's own? the includes() string method will only return true or false, never null

Comment: well  i tried console.log(e.name) it does return list of uppercase names , but used along with includes() it's returns `Uncaught TypeError: e.name is null` be it if I'm searching upper or lower case...

Comment: some object have value names of Null does this could have cause it ? i may need to filter out the object that have null in the property name ?

Comment: problem solved it's the proprieties that have null as a value in their own objects turn out i needed to filter them out thanks for the help !